# Options markup data not shown in analysis tab in drupal

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-webform

```
Drupal 7.35
Webform 7.x-4.8
webform_optionsmarkup-7.x-2.0-alpha1
```

Webform which contains options markup field analysis tab didn't show the data for options markup field.

Steps to reproduce issue:
1: Create field for options markup "Vote" set options to `"key_1 | Red key_2 | Blue key_3 | Green"` and select multiple options.

2: Submit data for webform

3: Click on Results then select analysis tab

4: Click on `"Add analysis components"` and select the field which created then click on update analysis details

5: It shows blank `data(Issue)`.